# Assign weaker access to method overriding from superclass

Tags: java, extend, privileges

I have a Class called `Module` which has a Method `onEnable();`
Now i have a class called `Config` and want to make the `onEnable();` method `private` because there is a predefined acting and a class extending `Config` should'nt be allowed to change the behaviour.

Is there any way to do this?

Example

```
class Module{

     public void onEnable(){

     }
}
```

A  class extending Module which is allowed to use `onEnable`:

```
class HelloWorldModule{

     @Override
     public void onEnable(){

          System.out.println("Hello, World!");

     }


}
```

Now the config Class, where i want that `onEnable` is private so that Classes which extend Config cannot! Override `onEnable`:

```
class Config{

    @Override
    private void onEnable(){
    }


}
```

So NOW, a class named `ProgrammConfig` which extends `Config` cannot override `onEnable`.

However, this is not working because you cannot override a `public` method to a `private` method.

Comment: So the `Config` class is extending `Module` class?

Comment: Yes. And then there are some other classes just extending Module. But the classes extending config which is extending module shouldnt be able to override onEnable

Comment: Your requirement isn't very clear, can you please redefine the problem and requirement. If possible present some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By declaring a method as `public`, you are saying that it should be possible to call said method on every instance of this class, including subclasses.  Declaring a method as `private` in a subclass doesn't make sense, and is thus not allowed.

Now, if you're concerned about subclasses overriding the method, you can declare the method as `final` to prevent this:

```
class Config extends Module{

    @Override
    public final void onEnable(){}
        //Whatever
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve this using inheritance. If `Config` is a subclass of `Module`, then it *must* provide all functions of `Module` with (at most) the same access restrictions. Think of a subclass as a specialized version of the superclass: It can do everything the superclass can, likely more, but never less.

Still you can implement a `Config` class as desired. Just skip subclassing, and instead use a private field of type `Module` like so:

```
class Config {
    private Module module;

    public Config() {
        module = new Module();
    }

    public int SomeFunctionFromModuleYouWantToExpose() {
        return module.SomeFunctionFromModuleYouWantToExpose();
    }

    // ...
}
```